# add dynamic sized rectangles to scene

Tags: java, javafx

I have an arraylist of lists containing strings

And I have turned these strings into text objects through nested loops. 
I have the height and width of these its just when I try to place them on the scene I cannot specify an x,y value so they appear at the top. How do I place the objects onto the scene without overlapping. ideally the first object being in the centre of the scene and others around but just getting them on the scene would be a start.

Here is what I have so far. The rectangle was to make it more obvious to me that there was a border around the object.

```
 TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();
    Group group = new Group(textFlow);

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 1200, 600, Color.WHITE);
    stage.setTitle("WordCloud");

    Integer size = 150;
    String family = "Arial";

    final Rectangle redBorder = new Rectangle(0, 0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    redBorder.setStroke(Color.RED);
    redBorder.setManaged(false);

    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Loop through arrayList to get each individual list
    for (List e : list2) {
        //System.out.println(e);
        //this will decrease the font size for strings in each list
        size = (size - 30);
        //Random colour generator
        int red = rand.nextInt(255);
        int green = rand.nextInt(255);
        int blue = rand.nextInt(255);

        for (Object d : e) {
           System.out.println(d);

            Text text = new Text(x,y,(String) d);
            //gives it font and size depending on index of the list
            text.setFont(Font.font(family, size));
            //random colour generator being used
            text.setFill(Color.rgb(red, green, blue, .99));
            text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);
            textFlow.setPrefWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            textFlow.setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            textFlow.setLayoutX(scene.getWidth());
            textFlow.setLayoutY(scene.getHeight());
            text.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                redBorder.setLayoutX(text.getBoundsInParent().getMinX());
                redBorder.setLayoutY(text.getBoundsInParent().getMinY());
                redBorder.setWidth(text.getBoundsInParent().getWidth());
                redBorder.setHeight(text.getBoundsInParent().getHeight());
            });


            group.getChildren().addAll(text, redBorder);

        }
    }
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

I have more code with a packing class that I have not added, this gave me an x, y value to pack into a 'bin' but I am unsure how to add the objects to the scene.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to run your code to get an idea of what you are doing and what's the problem, but your code is not runnable as is.

Comment: There are plenty of layouts available, just choose one that suits your needs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102 For more exotic layouts you probably need to implement your own layout algorithm, but this shouldn't be much of a problem requirements that are too complex. However you haven't provided a suitable description of the desired layout to allow us to recommend anything.

Comment: @fabian I am not sure which type of pane to use to get the layout I require. I want all the objects placed next to each other with the boundaries of the boxes touching. I am making a word cloud if that gives you more of an idea of what I am after?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Ah sorry the code was taken from my ide where an arraylist of lists is passed into list 2, my mistake.

Comment: Did you try using [FlowPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html)?

Comment: @HypnicJerk yeah I tried a flowplane which placed them sequentially but today my supervisor told me oh no don't do that just place them in the centre and detect a collision and place it in a spiral pattern around it and drew some rectangles. I understand it in plain english but just not how to do it in java ha.